# spring Websockets with stomp in tomcat server and rabbit mq as message broker - Load testing connection failure

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Using spring Websockets with stomp in tomcat server and rabbit mq as message broker.

When tried running without RabbitMQ as relay broker, it allowed maximum around 10000 connection. (limited based on max connections allowed in tomcat)

When tried using RabbitMQ as relay broker (hosted in AWS - single instance), It is failing after certain number of connections(4000) while doing load testing. (In RabbitMQ changed the config file for 
 - Filedescriptors 10000, socket descriptors 8908, memory 2.8 GB). 
Heart beat is set to zero for stompclient. Tried increasing Java client heap memory.

After more than 4000 connection it is failing. Is there any limitation to verify in RabbitMQ or is there any way to load test?

```
java.lang.Exception: {message=[Connection to broker closed.], content-length=[0]}   
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.invokeHandler(DefaultStompSession.java:435)
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.handleMessage(DefaultStompSession.java:421)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While configuring rabbitMQ as relay broker from websocket, heartbeats are set to 10 sec. By changing the heartbeat to zero it started working for more connections without any issues.